# Why is VS for Mac putting Nuget package version in the project packagereference, yet VS registers this is an error?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, nuget

I'm new to .NET and Visual Studio (for Mac).

When I install or update a Nuget package it puts the version on the packagereference in the project file rather than where I believe it is supposed to go (in the Directory.Packages.props file). At least VS complains about this and stops the package install. I then have to manually edit the project file to remove the version specification and place (or update) it in the Directory.Package.props file.

This makes any installs or updates of packages a time-consuming task :-(

What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Personally, I could understand why different project may want different versions of a package, so think putting it in the project file makes sense, but (as mentioned) VS complains.  I am using the Ardalis Clean Architecture solution template, so perhaps something is configured in there for its approach, I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Cheers,
Ashley.

PS I am using the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac (17.5.7 in 2023) and the latest Ardalis Clean Architecture template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac is a different codebase from Visual Studio (Windows) and doesn't have feature parity at this time.

In the developer community for Visual Studio for Mac there is an open issue that "[Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management)" (i.e. the Directory.Packages.props file) is not supported. See the "[NuGet Central Package Management does not supported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/NuGet-Central-Package-Management-does-no/10267650)" issue and add your vote.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, that explains things (the template is probably most often used on Window).  Can you please suggest what I should do (until CMP) is implemented?

Comment: I think this is an IDE issue and the command line tools may work fine. Try to use the `dotnet` CLI tool to add packages. nuget.exe 6.2.0 or later and .NET SDK 6.0.300 or later are required for CPM and the current versions for macOS satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Brilliant @jonathan-dodds, thank you!  I am comfortable with the command line, and that should work fine.